# Android view to be centered dynamically in an activity

Tags: android

How can one center align a view on a mobile screen in a complex activity programmatically without knowing the actual layout structure?

Lets say I have an activity layout like this...

```
<CUSTOMFRAMELAYOUT> //referring to a class extending FRAMELAYOUT
  < LINEARLAYOUT-1>
    <FRAMELAYOUT-1>
        <LINEARLAYOUT-2>
            <TEXTVIEW-1/>
        </LINEARLAYOUT-2>
    </FRAMELAYOUT-1>
    <FRAMELAYOUT-2>
    </FRAMELAYOUT-2>
  </LINEARLAYOUT-1>
</CUSTOMFRAMELAYOUT>
```

Now without knowing how the layout is defined, I want to remove 'TEXTVIEW-1' from its existing position and want to center it to the root layout

... in this case, the root layout is < CUSTOMFRAMELAYOUT>

Answer (score 0):

Rough guess,

find screen width and height
find textview width and height

calculate the top left point from above info. so that the textview will be in centre

set left and top margin of textview.

Comment: I worked on this one, but did not work. The solution I am looking for should be a generic one that suits all layouts.